# WordPress (Travelify Theme) menu code file

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm using the Travelify Theme on my WP site and I want to change the position of just one item on the menu. Therefore I would like to know where is the code file that generates the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order of menu items from the WordPress dashboard, without editing any code.

> Once an item is added to a menu, those menu items can be rearranged. Placing the mouse cursor over the menu item title, when the mouse cursor changes to 4-arrows, hold the left-mouse button down, drag the module to where you want to place it, then release the mouse button (this is called drag-and-drop).

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-order-of-menu-tabs

Comment: I think the OP is asking for the code to change it specifically, and not just looking to move things.

Comment: That's it, Christian. I want to move an item away from others.